# EKEventStore removeEvent EKErrorDomain Code=11 EKErrorObjectBelongsToDifferentStore

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, eventkit, ekevent

I am getting an error:

**removing event error: Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=11 "That event does not belong to that event store." UserInfo=0x1fdf96b0 {NSLocalizedDescription=That event does not belong to that event store.**

When I try to remove an EKEvent I just created.

The code below shows that I am storing the eventIdentifier and using it to retrieve the event. Furthermore when I do this, and NSLog the event I can see all the properties of it correctly.

From all the examples I have seen I am doing everything correctly. I also NSLog'ed the EKEventStore's eventStoreIdentifier and its the same every time I access it in any of my methods so it should be the same EKEventStore.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (EKEvent *) getCurrentCalendarEvent {
    NSString *currentCalendarEventID = [[UserModel sharedManager] currentCalendarEventID];
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [eventStore eventWithIdentifier:currentCalendarEventID];
    return event;
}

- (void) removeCurrentCalendarEvent {
    EKEvent *event = [self getCurrentCalendarEvent];
    if (event) {
        NSError *error;
        EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        [eventStore removeEvent:event span:EKSpanFutureEvents error:&error];
    }
}

- (void) addCurrentCalendarEvent {
    [self removeCurrentCalendarEvent];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = [[UserModel sharedManager] reminderLabel];
    event.notes = @"Notes";

    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    int futureDateSecs = 60 * 5;
    NSDate *endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:futureDateSecs];

    event.startDate = startDate;
    event.endDate = endDate;

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    NSError *error;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];

    [[UserModel sharedManager] setCurrentCalendarEventID:event.eventIdentifier];
    [[UserModel sharedManager] saveToDefaults];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This is happening because you are `always initializing a new instance of EKEventStore`. When you are adding `EKEvent` to `EKEventStore` then the instance of `EKEventStore` is different then when you are trying to remove. What you can do is that declare `EKEventStore` reference variable in .h and initialize it only one time.

in .h -

```
EKEventStore *eventStore;
```

in .m -

inside `viewDidLoad` -

```
eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

then remove this line from all of three methods-

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
Weird thing is that did cross my mind but I also figured that because the instance of EKEventStore was not going to persist once the app closed, that the whole point of eventIdentifier was to refetch that event in the future.
This further confused me when I was able to fetch the event from any of my instances of EKEventStore with the eventIdentifier.
I am unsure why someone would want more than 1 instance of EKEventStore but surely a class method for creating and fetching these events to a singleton would be the best way for most uses.

Anyway glad to solve this one. Cheers!